# Change a table value with a loop in lua

Tags: loops, lua, key-value, lua-table

I'm trying to change a value inside a table but I can't.

This is my code:

```
table = {{x=2}, {y=3}, {z=2}}

function printTabValue(tab, index)
    for k, v in pairs(tab[index]) do
        print(k, v)
    end
end

for k, v in pairs(table[1]) do
    print(k,v)
    table[k] = 5
end

printTabValue(table,1)
```

I get this result:

> > Executing task: lua54 c:\Users\Fabio\Documents\tabletop\randomSpawnWithChat.lua <
>
> x       2
>
> x       2
>
> Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.

So, the value is the same.

How can I edit the value inside the table?

Comment: Replace `table[k] = 5` with `table[1][k] = 5`

Comment: Replace all occurances of ```table``` with another not used keyword. Because ```table``` already exists and holds function/methods. Also known as library: https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#6.6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
table = {{x=2}, {y=3}, {z=2}}
```

is equivalent to

```
table = {
  [1] = {x=2},
  [2] = {y=3},
  [3] = {z=2},
}
```

`table[1]` only has one field `"x"` so after running your loop

```
for k, v in pairs(table[1]) do
    print(k,v)
    table[k] = 5
end
```

which can be replaced by

`table["x"] = 5` or `table.x = 5`

your table looks like this:

```
table = {
  [1] = {x=2},
  [2] = {y=3},
  [3] = {z=2},
  x = 5,
}
```

To change a single value all you need to do is this:

```
table[1].x = 5
```